# create external table with datetime/date-column from parquet with Synapse

Tags: t-sql, parquet, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I try to create an external table from an external file stored in my Azure datalake.
But I struggle with datetime and date columns in parquet-files!

Here is the code with which I try to create the external-Table 
PS: I also tried using date and datetime but got errors.. though varchar should yield at least something, right?

```
create external table [parquet_userdata]
(
    registration_time [varchar] (100) null,
    id [varchar] (10) null,
    first_name [varchar] (100) null,
    last_name [varchar] (100) null,
    email [varchar] (100) null,
    gender [varchar] (100) null,
    ip_address [varchar] (100) null,
    cc [varchar] (100) null,
    country [varchar] (100) null,
    birthday [varchar] (100) null,
    salary [float] null,
    title [varchar] (100) null,
    comments [varchar] (2000) null
)
with(
    -- specify the file in container
    location= 'userdata.parquet',
    data_source = parquet_location,
    file_format = parquetformat
)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Here is the data that I used (I took userdata1.parquet):
https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/sample-data/parquet
In case of doubt about the usability of the data, here we can quickly validate the content of the data and what it should look like:
https://www.parquet-viewer.com/#parquet-online

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the external table your creating using parquet files is sensitive to column names.
You need to give exact names.

Below is the result got for this command.

```
create  external  table [parquet_userdata_c]
(
    c1 [varchar] (1000) null,
    c2 [varchar] (10) null,
    c3 [varchar] (100) null,
    c4 [varchar] (100) null,
    c5 [varchar] (100) null,
    c6 [varchar] (100) null,
    c7 [varchar] (100) null,
    c8 [varchar] (100) null,
    c9 [varchar] (100) null,
    c10 [varchar] (1000) null,
    c11 [float] null,
    c12 [varchar] (100) null,
    c13 [varchar] (2000) null
)
with(
location='/data/Databricks/userdata1.parquet',
data_source = parquet_location,
file_format = user_file_format
);
```

Output:

[image]

So, after adding exact names.

```
create  external  table [userdata]
(
    registration_dttm DATETIME2(7) null,
    id [varchar] (10) null,
    first_name [varchar] (100) null,
    last_name [varchar] (100) null,
    email [varchar] (100) null,
    gender [varchar] (100) null,
    ip_address [varchar] (100) null,
    cc [varchar] (100) null,
    country [varchar] (100) null,
    birthdate [varchar] (1000) null,
    salary [float] null,
    title [varchar] (100) null,
    comments [varchar] (2000) null
)
with(
    location='/data/Databricks/userdata1.parquet',
    data_source = parquet_location,
    file_format = user_file_format
    );
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't now the column name, you check with the `OPENROWSET` as below.

```
SELECT
    TOP  5 *
FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK  'https://jgsblob.blob.core.windows.net/data/Databricks/userdata1.parquet',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
) AS [result]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you!
Is case-sensitivity always active for parquet files with azure-sql?

Comment: Yeah, when creating external table the column names show be given exactly.